# How to make table cell animation extend on hover

Tags: css, html-table, slide

I have a problem with css animation.

In my case I have table with 2 languages. On language hover, I want the table to extend to full width of the table... current code works only on first language... If I hover over second element the cell only strutters, it doesn't extend to left direction.

Here's a snippet

```css
.locale-wrapper {
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;    
}

.locale-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;  
}

.locale-text:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="locale-wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td class="locale-text">SL</td>
    <td class="locale-text">EN</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "*I want the table to extend to full width of the table*" - in what way is the `<table>` not already the full width of the `<table>`?

Comment: You have `a:hover`, but there are no anchor elements in your HTML? should that be `.locale-text:hover`?

Comment: Don't understand what you want. Please clarify what do you expect

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Filipinjo/ad6juw34/3/ on EN it doesn/t extend in reverse way :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix the size of your `table` to `80px`and your `td`width to `50%` you know that there's only two cell then use `40px` instead of `50%`it doesn't work on the second cause the first try to keep his `50%` of `width`. And fix your `:hover`width in `px` too.

Working example :

```css
.locale-wrapper {
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;    
}

td.locale-text{
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;  
}

td.locale-text:hover {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<table class="locale-wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td class="locale-text">SL</td>
    <td class="locale-text">EN</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code: Hope this will help you.

```css
.locale-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.locale-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 2%;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.locale-text:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="locale-wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td class="locale-text">SL</td>
    <td class="locale-text">EN</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use snippets in answers to show a working version. Also, your answer only half works.